# Php file giving error while using variable

Tags: php, variables, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

using this php gives error 500, any help is appreciated.

what i want is to make the below URL behave like--- api.telegram.org/bot1A/sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=Hellow

```
<?php

$msg= Hellow
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot1A/sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=".echo $msg->plaintext;  );
// Do what you want with result
?>
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the PHP error log to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: But I can tell you now that you have some trivial syntax errors - `$msg= Hellow` needs a `;` at the end. And also you can't write `echo` inside another string, or put a `;` in there. `echo $msg->plaintext;` should just be `$msg->plaintext` since you're concatenating it. Please use an IDE or text editor which understands PHP and which would highlight these problems to you before you even tried to run the code. There are many free ones available.

Comment: Hello ADyson, thanks for the reply, here is the error [11-Jan-2021 10:55:51 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/bpr7142ayake/public_html/snap/bot/bot.php on line 4

Comment: See this guide for general advice: [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: dear ADyson, I would like to make the URL to behave like
https://api.telegram.org/bot1A/sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=Hellow

Comment: It should be just `$msg= Hellow;
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot1A/sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=".$msg);`. Not sure why you put `echo` in there, or where you think `->plaintext` is coming from - $msg is just a string, it doesn't have any properties like that, it's not an object. I think you need to make some more basic study of PHP before you worry about calling APIs and all that.

Comment: ADyson my man, You're a life saver, thanks a ton buddy. God bless, this solved the issue.

Comment: No problem. Like I said, this is really basic syntax and you need to make sure you understand these basics before you move on. And please use an IDE or text editor which can highlight PHP syntax errors for you.

Answer (score -1):

Hellow needs to be quoted if a string or trailing parenthesis need to be given if its a function call, if its the latter convention is not to have a capital letter as the first letter in a functions name.

```
$msg = 'Hellow';
```

or

```
$msg = Hellow();
```

You can also drop the echo inside the `file_get_contents` argument, you wont need it

Comment: It's not the only problem.

Comment: Yes, I want to make URL to behave like 
https://api.telegram.org/bot1A/sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=Hellow